# Is there a way to add a global cooldown to my commands so when one user uses the command, all users have to wait the specific time?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, I have a Call All Staff system designed for my Discord server but I want it so when one user uses it, every user must wait 30 minutes before using it again.
here's my code:

```js
  var callallstaff = ['<@&791604815620603904>']

  if (callallstaff.some(w => ` ${message.content.toLowerCase()} `.includes(` ${w} `))) {

    var warn = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Call All Staff')
      .setDescription('Your about to mention all staff members of this server. \n \n **ONLY use for emergencies**, abusing this will result in a warn. \n \n Do you want to continue? Respond with \`yes`\ or \`no`\ ')
      .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.tag}`)
      .setColor('#ff0000')
    message.channel.send(warn)
    message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == message.author.id, {max: 1, time: 30000}).then(collected => {
      if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == 'yes') {
        message.channel.send(`<@&757974725359042600> -Requested by ${message.author}`)
      }
      else {
        message.channel.send('Canceled!')
      }
    }).catch(() => {
      message.channel.send('Timed out!')
    })
  }
```

However, I do know how to make a cooldown for only one user so only that user gets the cooldown but I'm unsure on how to set it so all users must wait,
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this:

- Get a timestamp of the current time when the user sends the command
- Calculate a timestamp of the time 30 mins after this
- When the user tries the command, get the current time again
- If the current time is greater than the timestamp you calculated, then it has been thirty minutes

Now, I haven't put much effort into this, but here is some basic code that may help you with your development:

```js
let cooldown = 0; // define this somewhere above
// call all staff command detected
let currentTime = new Date(Date.now());
if (currentTime.getTime() < cooldown) {
    message.reply("cooldown active, please try again later!");
} else {
    // do commmand
    cooldown = currentTime.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000); // adds 30 mins to current time
}
```